# what does it mean to build LDAP V3 compliant application?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have a requirement to build build a few REST api that interface with an LDAP V3 compliant server such as open LDAP/ AD. My primary question is if a server is LDAP v3 compliant, does it have its attributes defined per a standard L[as opposed to something like samAccount in AD]? that way it is possible to build a single integration code that integrates with all LDAP V3 severs. so if I have to create/query a user on any LDAP V3 server, I use that same code using standard LDAP attributes and not use vendor specific attributes such as "samaaccount ", or "memberOf". Is this possible at all [just like if I were to write JPA compliant code I could use both hibernate, eclipselink as ORM providers]? or have I misinterpreted LDAP v3 compliance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAPv3 is about capabilities, not about attributes. Depending on which Schemata are used the attributes an LDAP-Server can hold differ. Therefore you can not expect an LDAPv3-compatible server to identify users with a fix attribute-type. You can expect an LDAPv3-compatible server to be capable of understanding SASL, Referrals or Controls. But you will need to make the attributes you need to use configurable depending on the used LDAP-Backend.

Comment: Thanks heiglandreas. that nailed it for me.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to mark it as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The attributes that are used are going to vary from directory to directory and even amongst implementations of the same directory. Every application I've seen that does this properly provides a screen or configuration file for the administrator to map the attributes in the application to the corresponding LDAP directory attributes.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am with you on the fact that directory configuration differs from vendor to vendor. My question is whether LDAP V3 creates standard attribute names for configuration parameters [and complied to by vendors that are V3 ready] which help developers write the integration code once and use the same code while switching between multiple vendors seamlessly. For example if I were to stick a standard JPA [Java Persistence API] implementation, I could plug in any of the ORM implementation such as eclipselink, hibernate. Is something like that available while using LDAP V3 servers.

Comment: Is my understanding/interpretation a misconception about LDAP V3 compliance?

Comment: You'll find there's a `supportedControls` attribute on the `RootDSE` of the directory which will have a series of standardized entries to tell you what the directory is capable of. What it won't tell you is which attribute someone's username is stored in, for example.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Will check that.

Answer (score 0):

LDAPv3 is a standard protocol, data model and schema that can be extended.
In my opinion, building a service to access an LDAPv3 compliant server must use the protocol and data model, and understand the default/ standard schema, but must be configurable on the attributes, the objectclasses and the directory structure.